# CSS Grid apply template columns to child div through inline style

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm in scenario where I can add **inline CSS** to only one div.

For example:

```
<div class="main" style="my inline CSS">
  <div class="second">
    <div class="third">
       <div class="column></div>
       <div class="column></div>
       <div class="column></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to apply `grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;` (note: this can change) to the div `third` - the div nesting the `column` divs. As I mentioned I can add inline CSS only to div `main`.

Using the CSS grid system, is it possible to target the child div?

Note: In this scenario there is no access to the stylesheet - only inline style in the `main` div.

Comment: if you add more context, there is probably another solution.

Comment: Another solution would be using js to add the inline style where I want or and <style> in the body.. but trying to see if this is possible first.

Comment: If those are the only 2 options, use <style>. Simple solution to a simple problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## With CSS? Nope.

The style attribute's only scope is one specificity lower than `!important` for that element. It only accepts attributes, not selectors.